What's the deal with Daemon's unsettling dream about his mother?
In House of the Dragon (Season 2, Episode 5: "Regent"), Daemon Targaryen experiences a pretty disturbing dream or vision while at Harrenhal. He's getting intimate with a Targaryen woman… who turns out to be his own mother, Alyssa. Talk about awkward! This whole scene might be the result of Alys Rivers messing with his head, or it could be the spooky castle playing tricks on him.
Alys Rivers even drops a not-so-subtle hint about it, telling Daemon, "It's a pity, don't you think, that you never knew your mother." This dream is messed up on so many levels. We all know the Targaryens are cool with a bit of family love, but even they draw the line at parent-child hookups. This is way beyond their usual incest shenanigans.
So, what's Alys Rivers' game here if she's behind this mind-bending dream? And what does this creepy vision tell us about Daemon's inner workings? Is it supposed to reveal something about his personality or his deepest, darkest desires? Could this be a manifestation of some unresolved Oedipus complex, or is it just a way to mess with Daemon's head?

Are you asking for speculation, or spoilers from the book?

Before we see the rest of the show, it's not information, it's spoilers. Alys in the books is described as a magic user of sorts, but I think it is premature to say what the show will make of it.

@TLP I don't mind spoilers from book information.

@TLP Speculation based on available information, books, or otherwise is fine with me too.
